# Why does an HTTP request in Node.js yield the data type as well?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, express, form-post

```
  req = http.request options, (res) ->
    res.on 'data', (chunk) ->
      data += chunk
      return
    res.on 'end', ->
      if res.statusCode is 200
        console.log res
        console.log data
        callback null, data
      else
        callback(new Error("Response status code: " + res.statusCode), data)
      return
    return
```

When I output data, I get:
`[object Object][["INZ", 41.878113599999999, -87.629798199999996]]` which is odd because the part after `[object Object]` is all good. Any ideas?

Comment: You're only doing `data += chunk`, which implies data is defined and initialized elsewhere. Where's the rest of the code?

Comment: This uses `CoffeeScript` so `data` is initialized in the beginning of this particular scope

Comment: Yes, but it's undefined when first initialized and the only time you're setting it is with `+=`, so you're doing `undefined += something` which is bad, unless you're setting data somewhere else first.

Comment: Right, what Brian said. You should really put the line `data = ''` right before your `res.on`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not defining `data`, so you're getting `undefined += chunk`, as I said in my comment. You can solve it like @Trevor Burnham said:

```
req = http.request options, (res) ->
  data = ''
  res.on 'data', (chunk) ->
    data += chunk
    return
...
```